# Столкновение круга и угла прямоугольника

Tags: java, android, геометрия, 2d

Пишу 2D игру, в которой есть неподвижные стены и круг, который может двигаться. Определяю, что они столкнулись с помощью предыдущей позиции круга и текущей(дабы исключить такое, что круг на больших скоростях может перелететь стену). Соответственно, определяю момент столкновения(позицию круга), для того чтобы рассчитать его дальнейшее движение.Проблем с определением столкновения с одной из сторон стены нет, но есть с проблемы с углом стены. Я также могу определить точку угла, с которым круг врезался. После чего стоит вопрос математики: Как определить позицию (красного на рисунке) круга.
[image: Рисунок, чтобы всё было понятно]
Жёлтым показаны все точки, которые известны. От центра красного круга до точки угла = R круга 
Известен также угол направления движения круга в радианах.

Comment: вам надо определить, пересекаются ли две прямые, одна из сторон стены и одна из касательных к двум окружностям

Comment: Я так и делаю, суть не в том, чтобы определить столкнулся ли круг или нет.А в том, чтобы найти где он столкнулся

Comment: Высоту из угла стены на прямую соединяющие центры. Гипотенуза равна радиусу круга.

Comment: В принципе можно и расчет столкновения переделать на центральную линию. Длина высоты должна быть больше R

Comment: @rjhdby так, хорошо, сейчас попробую разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x1,y1 - координаты центра первого круга

x2,y2 - координаты центра второго круга

R - радиус круга

A - угол между прямой центров и радиусом из центра искомой окружности к углу стены

xx, yy - координаты угла стены

Прямая, соединяющая центры:

```
(y1-y2)X+(x2-x1)y+(x1y2-x2y1)=0
A*X+B*Y+C=0
```

Расстояние от угла стены до прямой центров:

```
D=|A*xx+B*yy+C|/sqrt(A*A+B*B)
```

Столкновение было, если `D < R`

```
sin(A)=D/C
```

PS Ну а дальше банальная задача нахождение координат вершины прямоугольного треугольника